# How to get story string in different languages via GraphApi in Android?

Tags: android, json, facebook-graph-api, localization

i am using Facebook Graph API to get user's feed. But when i get string which is defined "story", it comes in English what i do. Should i do get it different languages ? How/Where i can use "locale" value(fr_FR or tr_TR) while i am doing query ? Here's my code:

EDIT: FacebookFeed is my POJO class.

```
    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(FacebookScreen.getMe(), Arrays.asList("user_posts"));

            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "created_time,story,message,link,picture");

        GraphRequest request = new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "/v2.3/me/feed", parameters, HttpMethod.GET, new Callback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {

                        JSONObject object = response.getJSONObject();

                        for (int i = 0; i < object.optJSONArray("data").length(); i++) {
                            FacebookFeed feed = new FacebookFeed();
                            if (object.optJSONArray("data").optJSONObject(i).optString("story") != null) {
                                feed.setStory(object.optJSONArray("data").optJSONObject(i).optString("story"));
                                Log.i("log1", "if1");
                            }
                            if (object.optJSONArray("data").optJSONObject(i).optString("message") != null) {
                                feed.setMessage(object.optJSONArray("data").optJSONObject(i).optString("message"));
                                Log.i("log2", "if2");
                            }
                            if (object.optJSONArray("data").optJSONObject(i).optString("created_time") != null) {
                                feed.setTime(object.optJSONArray("data").optJSONObject(i).optString("created_time"));
                                Log.i("log3", "if3");



                            }
                            if (object.optJSONArray("data").optJSONObject(i).optString("picture") != null) {
                                String urlString=object.optJSONArray("data").optJSONObject(i).optString("picture");
                                feed.setPicture(urlString);
                                Log.i("log4", "if4");   

                            }
                            if (object.optJSONArray("data").optJSONObject(i).optString("link") != null) {
                                feed.setLink(object.optJSONArray("data").optJSONObject(i).optString("link"));
                                Log.i("log5", "if5");
                            }

                            feedList.add(feed);
                            Log.i("LOG", "added to list");
                        }
}
});
request.executeAsync();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to add

```
parameters.putString("locale", "fr_FR");
```

This works at least in the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Ffeed%3Ffields%3Dcreated_time%2Cstory%2Cmessage%2Clink%2Cpicture%26locale%3Dfr_FR&version=v2.4):

Comment: Thanks a lot, my friend. it worked in the Graph API Explorer. Now, i will try to put in my code

Comment: Thank u very much Tobi, it works in my code, too. You saved me from a great ordeal.